# rest of element of page shows after jquery image slider finish loading

Tags: jquery, magento, flexslider

I am using flexi slider on magento community Homepage and I want other page content to show after the jquery image slider done loading (it has large images so it takes a lot of time to load)

Comment: Kindly show what you have tried till now??

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the async attribute on the script tags where you load the slider:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp